# Postgres trigger if a column has *NOT* been updated

Tags: postgresql, triggers

In a Postgres trigger, is it possible to find out if a given column has been included in the UPDATE list or not, even if the value has not changed? I'm looking for the equivalent of the `UPDATE()` function in SQL Server (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql)

I know I can create a trigger that only runs if a given column has been UPDATED, but I want the opposite, to only trigger if the column has *not* been UPDATED.

I have a trigger that runs on INSERT and UPDATE operations. As I said, I would like it to run only if the given column has *NOT* been specified. For INSERTs this is easy as I can check `NEW.column IS NULL`, but how do I check on UPDATE? I can't just check for `NEW.column != OLD.column` because I specifically want it *not to run* if the column has been set to the same value it already is, it should only run if the column has *not been included* in the UPDATE list.

The background for this is that we have a `source` column that we set automatically. Application layer UPSERTs do not set this value, and so we have a trigger to set it. We also have some postgres functions that can get called that lead to other UPSERTs, and these will set the `source` column. Currently in these functions, we disable the trigger, UPSERT the data and then re-enable the trigger. However we have found that the trigger disable/reenable is causing locking issues and so we are looking for a way to avoid this step. By only triggering if the `source` column is not specified on the UPSERT we can avoid the disable/reenable.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres does not have any direct equivalent. However it does provide the `when` conditional on [create trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html). Postgres also provides the `is [not] distinct from` predicate/clause which better handles nulls. Use it on the when clause create trigger:

```
create trigger some_trigger 
before update
    on some_table
  for each row 
 when (old.some_column is distinct from new.some_column)
 execute function some_column_not_updated_bur();
```

--- Update ---
What is your intent? Is it to just not fire the trigger or is it to suppress the update? What should happen when the specific column is updated but value not changed but some other column is changed?  I change the answer to fire the only when the is changed, but the update still happens, but the **trigger does not fire**. See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6_n8zI8g). Note in the demo the second update does not change the value of a specified column (`test_value`) but does change another column (`note`). However, it does not create a row in the table `trigger_log' indicating that the trigger did not fire.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to distinguish between the column not being updated (in which case I want the trigger to run) and the column being updated but the value not changing (in which case I don't want the trigger to run). This will run for both.

Comment: See update in answer.

Comment: Ok, breaking it down into different scenarios: (1) INSERT where "some_column" is not given a value => trigger fires. (2) INSERT where "some_column" is given a value => trigger does not fire. (3) UPDATE where "some_column" is not updated => trigger fires. (4a) UPDATE where "some_column" is updated but the value does not change => trigger does not fire. (4b) UPDATE where "some_column" is updated with a different value => trigger does not fire. The problem I have is distinguishing between (3) and (4a)

Comment: I have said "trigger does not fire" here, but this could also be "trigger fires but takes no action" of course